# Get rid of root object name in JSON using Jackson

Tags: spring-mvc, jackson, spring-annotations

I am using Jackson to create JSON strings to return from my spring mvc controllers.

The class I am trying to serialize to JSON looks like this:

```
class Stuff {
    private List<Element> elements;
    // getters and setters...
}
```

Now the API returns this:

```
{
    "stuff": {
        "elements": []
    }
}
```

What I want:

```
{
    "elements": []
}
```

Can I do this with annotations only? 
If yes, what annotations on the Stuff class should I use to get this working?

Comment: How exactly is the API returning `{
    "stuff": {
        "elements": []
    }
}` Can you please show your controller method? You are probable returning  some wrapper that contains `stuff`

Answer (score 0):

you can probably return a HashMap<String, Element[]>, where the key is "elements".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).